# Route::get with parameters and redirect

Tags: php, laravel

A client asks me to redirect an old URL to a new one. Only, the URL it gives me contains a parameter and it is impossible to do a .htaccess redirect with that. I tested and I did not succeed.

I would like to redirect with the Laravel route system.

I tried this :

```
Route::get('places.php?p=1740', function () {
   return redirect('new/url');
});
```

But I have the same problem. I have a 404 error that the page does not exist. I tried without the parameter and it works.

I also tried this:

```
Route::get('places.php/{p}', function ($p = '1740') {
    return redirect('new/url');
});
```

But it does not work either.

I just need a solution that works to redirect his url with a parameter to a new one.

Thank you !

Comment: If your webserver is setup properly, you shouldn't need `.php` in your routes; `Route::get("/places/{p}", ...)` should be fine. Navigating to `http://your-app/places/1740` should redirect you to `http://your-app/new/url`

Answer (score 0):

In laravel routing system you don't need to specify `.php` extension, use like below:

```
Route::get('places/{p}', function ($p = '1740') {
    return redirect('new/url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have an old url from a version of the website not built in Laravel and this url is probably indexed by search engines and users are hitting a 404 when visiting this url. And your goal is to setup up a 301 redirect from `https://example.com/places.php?p=1740` to  `https://example.com/new/url`.

If this is the case you should be able to achieve this by adding this line to `/public/.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /places.php?p=1740 /new/url
```

Or you might be able to do this via the routes file:

```
Route::redirect('/places.php?p=1740', '/new/url', 301);
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. Precisely because there is? P = 1740 in the URL. This is the first thing I tested.